# error in memoir: Command \newfloat already defined

Tags: floats, errors, memoir

Using this preamble:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,11pt,a4paper,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,wasysym}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkgray}{gray}{0.3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage[pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=darkgray, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

TexMaker gives this error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \newfloat already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: There's no error with the preamble you provided. If you are trying to load the package **float** afterwards, don't: **memoir** has its built-in mechanism for this. Never use the option `pdftex`.

Comment: Do you mean that I cant use memoir with pdftex?

Comment: no, just that there is no reason to specify the `pdftex` option. Packages that respond to it will detect it by themselfs

Answer (score 12):

Just for the record, I had the same problem, using `memoir` and `floatrow` together. Removing `pdflatex` from the preamble did not solve it.

I compiled the document successfully by adding the following line before loading `floatrow`:

```
\let\newfloat\undefined
\usepackage{floatrow}
```

Thanks to [Joseph Wright](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2009-07/msg00211.html).

Comment: thank you, it's worked for me

Answer (score 11):

There's no error with the preamble you provided. If you are trying to load the package **float** afterwards, don't: **memoir** has its built-in mechanism for defining new floating environments.

See p. 169 in the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf).